# Swift Unit Tests PLCrashReporter.h file not found

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, plcrashreporter

I'm using (linked) [PLCrashReporter.framework](https://github.com/plausiblelabs/plcrashreporter) in my main swift target, with the following in my bridging header:

```
#import "PLCrashReporter.h"
#import "PLCrashReport.h"
#import "PLCrashReportTextFormatter.h"
```

and the following Header Search Paths: `$(PROJECT_DIR)/Frameworks/CrashReporter.framework/Headers`

It works, but when I try to run my unit tests against the project, I get these two errors:

> /Users/me/dev/myapp-ios/MyApp/MyApp-Bridging-Header.h:7:9: 'PLCrashReporter.h' file not found

and

> Failed to import bridging header '/Users/me/dev/myapp-ios/MyApp/MyApp-Bridging-Header.h'

How can I help my UnitTests target see this objective-c framework's headers?

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: I have not yet. Might be related to cocoapods.

Comment: I did not even manage to get this to work in the normal build. If I try to import it in my bridging header, it says that it can't find the plcrashreport.h